# Using integers to encode short strings

Tags: algorithm, encoding, compression

Suppose I were limited to using only 32-bit unsigned integers to express strings. Obviously, I could use individual u8 numbers and allocate enough separate values to describe a short string, but say compute and time aren’t important, this being for my curiosity, not necessarily for a real world use.

I observe that a 32-bit number is the same size as 4 strict u8 chars. In decimal, there’s space to encode 4 of any character-encoding that could be indexed by a 2-digit decimal as their decimal equivalent, while 5 ECMA-1 characters could fit in the same bitsize.

Suppose I want the range of printable characters, using a mapped ASCII table, where I subtract 32 to get the printable characters into 2 decimal digits (32 to 126 become 0 to 94). Suppose a mapping function similar to |c,i|c-31*(10^((i+1)*2)), where c is the ASCII value and i is the position: 45769502. In ASCII values as a u8 array [66, 97, 116, 33], or the string “Bat!”

Clearly this is not computationally efficient. I’m not necessarily shooting for that? Just pure curiosity here.

Supposing compute is arbitrary, so even being totally absurd, how might I encode a longer string in a 32-bit unsigned integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to decide on which characters you want to encode. Suppose you have chosen `k` characters which you have mapped to the numbers 0 to `k-1`. Then every integer `n` is mapped to a unique non-empty string by expressing `n` in base `k` and mapping each `k`-ary digit to the corresponding character. You could reserve the maximum integer for the empty string.

So you just need a mapping table for the `k` characters and a [function to convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701517/algorithm-to-convert-integer-represented-as-an-array-with-base-n-to-integer-wi) an integer from one base to another, that's simple and efficient, and the encoding is also optimally dense (since every integer maps to a unique string).

Comment: I was thinking about it again this afternoon, and I realized that I'm implicitly doing that exact thing in a most inefficient way. Essentially, I've observed that one can encode base-100 mappings of symbols onto an int. My method was to first convert from base-2 to base-10, and then use two-digit base 10 representation -- effectively base-100, the long-way-round.

Looks like a base-73 is the most densely expressive I can get in a 32-bit space, with 5 characters encoded in a reasonable symbol-set.

I suppose with state machine semantics, I could be more expressive...but, eww.