# ASCII85 BASE64 Encoding in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm referring to http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/equipping-our-ascii-armor.html but I'm getting drastically different results.

Does anyone know how to duplicate his blog post examples in Ruby?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "drastically different results"? The blog post uses random numbers all over the place, so of course you will get drastically different results, everytime you run the code. Can you show an example of what your input is, what your output is and what the output is that you are expecting to get? Can you show the code you have so far? In short: can you show *anything at all* that would at least give a *hint* at what your actual problem is?

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/kylebragger/tiny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a random UUID the [`uuidtools`](http://uuidtools.rubyforge.org/) gem and output it as a hex string or an integer. The library also supports generating random strings:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'uuidtools'

uuid = UUIDTools::UUID.random_create
puts uuid.to_s
puts uuid.to_i

puts SecureRandom.hex
puts SecureRandom.base64
```

There's an existing [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894325/an-algorithm-for-converting-a-base-10-number-to-a-base-n-number) which discusses converting a number (use `to_i`) to ASCII 85 in Ruby.

I also found [Amp::Encoding::Base85](http://amp.carboni.ca/docs/Amp/Encoding/Base85.html#encode-class_method) which you can use with the `raw` output from `uuidtools`'.

Comment: The link seems to work converting a uuid from decimal to hex, Integer.to_s(16) but it doesn't work at all trying to convert base 85 to anything. "[Rb*hlkkXVW+q4s(YSF0".to_i(16) => 0

Comment: Using `Amp::Encoding::Base64`'s `decode` method and `UUID::parse_raw`, you should be able to decode a base 85 UUID into a native UUID again (which you could then convert back to hex).