# Ruby integer to string key

Tags: ruby, string, key

A system I'm building needs to convert non-negative Ruby integers into shortest-possible UTF-8 string  (should be octet string; see **Edit** below) values.  The only requirement on the strings is that their lexicographic order be identical to the natural order on integers.

What's the best Ruby way to do this?

We can assume the integers are 32 bits and the sign bit is 0.  This is successful:

```
(i >> 24).chr + ((i >> 16) & 0xff).chr + ((i >> 8) & 0xff).chr + (i & 0xff).chr
```

But it appears to be 1) garbage-intense and 2) ugly.  I've also looked at `pack` solutions, but these don't seem portable due to byte order.

FWIW, the application is Redis hash field names. Building keys may be a performance bottleneck, but probably not. This question is mostly about the "Ruby way".

**Edit**

Abpve I should have said "shortest possible string of octets" rather than UFT-8, since this is what Redis actually 
stores for field keys. @Mark Reed's excellent suggestion to try true UTF-8 packing ssems to work. The `redis` gem I am using seems to properly convert extended codes to octet sequences for Redis:  For example,

```
REDIS.hset('hash', [0x12345678].pack('U'), 'foo')
```

works fine. But then

```
REDIS.hkeys('hash')
```

returns

```
"\xFC\x92\x8D\x85\x99\xB8"
```

I need to verify the lexicographic order of these strings is correct, but it looks good so far.

**End edit**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it has to be valid UTF-8, you're not going to get much of an improvement over just encoding the code-point as a UTF-8 character; one of the features of UTF-8 is that encoded characters sort in the proper numeric order, and it only uses the minimal number of bytes necessary under the rules of the format.

```
[i].pack('U')
```

Note that UTF-8 is byte-oriented, so there are no endianness concerns.

If you didn't actually mean UTF-8, then please clarify what you did mean.

Comment: Thanks very much. See edit above. I think this will work fine.  Need more testing to be sure Redis lexical order matches int order.  Redis does not know about UTF-8, but lex order of the octets it stores ought to be good.

Comment: As I mentioned above, one of the features of UTF-8 is that ordering by bytes gives you the correct order for the code points as well.  The only thing that has to "know about" UTF-8 is whatever's doing the encoding and decoding; a dumb byte-based sorter will give the right ordering.

Comment: Right. Thanks. But I needed to look at Redis to verify its bytewise sort is doing the commonsense thing with Ruby's bytewise conversion.  Correctness involves legal liability.  Had to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be able to convert to any base, and use that output to chose your characters. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2895806/131227