# How to transpose a base-10 number into a numbering system with characters?

Tags: java, c#, algorithm

In a base-10 numbering system, each digit can be from 0 to 9. I want to "increase the resolution" of each digit to be 0-9abc...custom_set_of_letters. This way, I can convert a large integer number into a shorter alphanumeric string representation.

For example, the number 102234 would be something like "A45" ("A45" is not the actual answer I'm looking for, it's just to illustrate that the string version would be shorter thanks to having more digits)

C/C++/Java/C# answer would be much preferred. Thank you!

(custom_set_of_letters could be in a non-latin language, do not assume ASCII)

Comment: P.S. I do know about https://hashids.org, but I want to do my own thing here

Comment: I specified 0-9A-Z for simplicity sake, but in reality it will be 0-9ABC...custom_set_of_letters

Comment: How is `102234` would be something like `A45`? Which base is it? How do you know is `A45` baseX or baseZ system?

Comment: You can use a `Map` that holds all the conversions for your "custom set" and then use it to convert the number.  Pretty sure this question is too broad and needs more focus though.

Comment: In C# you can use [BigInteger.ToByteArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.tobytearray) to have compact presentation.

Comment: A45 is just an example, not an actual value! I wanted to demonstrate that the string version will end up shorter then the numeric version due to having more digits to work with.

As for "code writing service" -- I do have code written, it's larger than I like it to be and is inefficient (but works).

Comment: @Igor Krupin Then if you just want a `String` with shorter than the numeric version what is wrong with using @Eng.Fouad's answer?  Seems like you are not giving us all the information.  Also code you have written does us no good if you don't post any of it.

Comment: Wow, tough crowd, but all good. I have a specified set of characters, "FGHZY" that I would like to use in my numbering system. I thought to make things simpler I'll just say A-Z b/c why does it matter?  I could be doing things in Japanese, then how would `Integer.toString(int i, int radix)` work with Japanese characters? So I was hoping for a bit of a more generic answer that does not get hung up on characters used.

"A45" was just an example to illustrate  that the string version would be shorter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the relevant part of your code query and describe your difficulties. Please Learn about [how to privide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and have a look about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Paflow - I politely disagree. See an answer I initially stumbled upon (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894325/an-algorithm-for-converting-a-base-10-number-to-a-base-n-number)

The details in the question were anemic, but the community "got" what was being asked. My question was similar, and I've provided a few more details. As I've mentioned before, I DO have the code, but it's 212 lines. Looking at the answer I posted a link to, I knew this could be done with a few lines, adding my code would add no value ...

Comment: @J... "The point is that this isn't a proper QA question - it's a specification and a work request. That's what we all get paid to do" -- I agree with that. I was just working on something and knew I was heading the wrong path and I asked for help w/o specifying where I was stuck and showing the problem area. True. Not a typical StackOverflow question. Duly noted. Thank you for Code Golf link, I did not know about the site but yes that's a better place for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, I will do something like that:

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <string>
#include    <algorithm>

std::string ch_base (int i) {
    const std::string figures = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const int base = figures.length();
    std::string res;
    if (i == 0) return "0";
    while (i) {
        res += figures[i%base];
        i /= base;
    }
    int size = res.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i++) {
        std::swap (res[i], res[size-i-1]);
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int i = 102234;
    std::cout << i << " = " << ch_base(i) << "\n";
}
```

It can be easily adapted to a different set of figures.

EDIT: a simpler version here:

```
std::string ch_base (int i) {
    const std::string figures = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const int base = figures.length();
    std::string res;
    if (i == 0) return "0";
    while (i) {
        res.push_back(figures[i%base]);
        i /= base;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I got uv62 for 102234.

Comment: Thank you!!! That's the stuff!

Comment: If you want to use non-latin characters, you may have a look at `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`

Comment: Note that in my previous code, the order of the characters were reversed. Sorry. Corrected. New result is 26vu for 102234.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Integer.toString(int i, int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int,int)) with radix [`Character.MAX_RADIX (36)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_RADIX):

```
int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
String digit = Integer.toString(i, Character.MAX_RADIX);
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(digit);
```

**Output:**

```
2147483647
zik0zj
```

Comment: Appologies, I modified the question after I saw your answer. In reality, my digits will be 0-9ABC...custom_set_of_letters. Looking at the function you posted I don't think I can specify a custom letter set ....

Comment: P.S. "A45" is just an example (not an actual value)! I just wanted to demonstrate that the string version would end up shorter than the numeric version ...

Comment: @IgorKrupin Have a look on how `Integer.toString` is implemented on OpenJDK: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#L143 You can modify the array `digits` to include custom set of characters.

Comment: Looking at the code OpenJDK I could, but i was hoping to be something a bit more generic and works with non-latin languages. But thank you for the link.

Comment: @IgorKrupin There is nothing in the question about a custom set of letters. If you were referring to the comment, that is not part of the question. If you really want custom letters, then **edit** the question to clarify it. People coming to look at the question shouldn't have to muddle their way through all the comments to understand the question.

Comment: @Andreas I don't use StackOverflow often to *ask* questions, so I'm bit green on the flow. I did look for the "edit" button but could not find it! I thought it was poor UX that a question could not be edited, so I resorted to comments. And I agree that's not the correct approach. After reading your comment I doubled the efforts and found the tiny Edit link. Thank you, I'll know for next time.